# NetSuite SuiteTalk SOAP retrieve Amortization Schedule list

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to retrieve the list of Amortization Schedules from NetSuite using the SuiteTalk SOAP web services. The list is accessible in NetSuite UI by going to List -> Accounting -> Amortization Schedules. I am using the php library https://github.com/netsuitephp/netsuite-php.

It seems like retrieving this list is not possible using the SOAP web services. I can't find any classes for searching this record in the php library, and in NetSuite schema browser (https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/schema/record/account.html) there is no entry for Amortization Schedule.

I was wondering is my understanding correct that this list is not supported by SuiteTalk SOAP API? Appreciate your help.

I searched through the php library classes and can't find any related classes for Amortization Schedule search.

Comment: Record browser shows it.  https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/script/record/amortizationschedule.html

Comment: That is correct. But based on what I have seen previously, the records in Schema Browser is the ones available for SOAP integration.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite got back to me and said essentially this is not available in SOAP integration:

> The amortization schedule record is currently not a supported record
> for SOAP API.
>
> If you are comfortable exploring alternatives, You can fetch the data
> for the amortization schedule via ODBC (SuiteAnalytics Connect), or
> via SuiteScript.
>
> I have also checked REST API but as of now, the amortization schedule
> is listed as a beta and is, therefore, not recommended to be used in
> the production environment

Comment: Any chance that you were able to figure this out?